# XmlArray attribute applied to a List derived class

Tags: c#, arrays, attributes, xml-serialization

I have

```
public class Convolutions : List<Convolution> { }
```

Which serializes as xml:

```
<ArrayOfConvolution>
     <Convolution>
```

But I would like:

```
<Convolutions>
    <Convolution>
```

But it is not possible to use `[XmlArray("Convolutions")]` or `[XmlElement(ElementName = "Convolutions")]` on a class.
Anyway to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the root object, then:

```
[XmlRoot("Convolutions")]
public class Convolutions : List<Convolution> { }
```

If it is a member of another object, use attributes on the member.

Another approach, more flexible in many cases, is to use a separate wrapper object and **encapsulate** the list; frankly, inheriting from lists is not usually very helpful. The following would work:

```
public class Convolutions {
    [XmlElement("Convolution")]
    public List<Convolution> Items { get; set; }
}
```

or if you don't like `set` on your collection members:

```
public class Convolutions {
    private readonly List<Convolution> items = new List<Convolution>();
    [XmlElement("Convolution")]
    public List<Convolution> Items { get { return items; } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[XmlType("Convolutions")]
public class Convolutions : List<Convolution>{ }

Comment: Thanks - that works - probably XmlRoot more approriate - but really 6 or one half a dozen of the other...

Comment: XmlRoot only works when it's the root. XmlType works everytime.